# Scaling spring boot applications dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Anything in spring cloud to detect failed spring boot process and restart it?(In few cases WebLogic node manager detects failures and restart JVM. Not hystrix ) also, scale up or down spring boot instances dynamically on Linux machine. I have seen something with kubernetes pods which can scale up or down dynamically.

Comment: no, there's no kind of watchdog process in spring cloud

Comment: Thanks, what would be the best way to handle it outside spring cloud. I  thought of writing bash scripts to monitor to scale up or down  using supervisord. trying to see if there are any other possible options to explore.

Comment: Consider using Kubernetes for scaling containers of your application. This also keeps your application code clean in favor of better local functional testability.

Comment: As for a watchdog for a java application, you can take a look and evaluate Tanuki Java Service Wrapper. It allows to run Java application as OS services as well as a watchdog Java process pinging your Java app at a configurable interval.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides the means for reporting detectable failure modes, it's up to your service orchestration technology to act upon that information.

The actuator [`/health`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-health) endpoint is designed to detect problematic services. It works by aggregating health statuses provided by different beans, including those which you define, sorting them and choosing the most severe from the sorted list as the 'overall' status.

Possible statuses in the default implementation are `DOWN`, `OUT_OF_SERVICE` and `UP` but you can replaces these as well as replace how the overall status is chosen.

As an example of service orchestration, kubernetes supports a periodic *liveness* check that runs against your running pods. We have this programmed to bounce our servers if the check fails to make the HTTP call (unresponsive JVM), returns an HTTP error or returns `200` with a status of `DOWN`.